# How can I start a JobScheduler immediately?

Tags: android

I set `setPeriodic` for a `JobScheduler`, I feel that the `JobScheduler` will not work if I close the APP at once after I invoke `startScheduleRestore`.
Because the value interval of `setPeriodic(interval)` is 10min, but the APP has closed quickly, so I think the `JobScheduler` will not work. Right?

So I hope to start a `JobScheduler` immediately, you know this `JobScheduler` will be fired about after 10min. How can I do? Thanks!

**Code**

```
private fun startScheduleRestore(mContext:Context){
   val interval=10 *60 *1000L

    val mJobScheduler = mContext.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

    val jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(mContext.getInteger(R.integer.JobID), ComponentName(mContext, RestoreService::class.java))
                        .setPeriodic(interval)
                        .setPersisted(true)
                        .build()

    mJobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)
}
```